# Re-record audio in ios swift voicememo app

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording

I'm building a custom voice memo app in swift 4 for iOS12.

How can I implement re-recording at a previous point in the recording? 
(Like apples official voice memo app)

I have searched the AVFoundation documentation but can't find any reference of such functionality.

Perhaps using multiple tracks could be a solution?

Example use case:

- Start recording, record for 15 seconds
- Pause the recording
- Scrub back 10 seconds in the recording
- Resume recording for five seconds
- Pause and scrub back to end and continue recording

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried to make it happen?

Comment: I haven’t really tried anything substancial yet.

Comment: Ur giving correct solution, you have to go with multiple tracks as i know.Try to save timings in an array, and at the end trim the audio according to the timings and then merge the audio with AVFoundation API.